Show Campaign Files on Lead/Contact
My Sales Development team would like to see what content a potential customer saw.
So Marketo is syncing campaign information, adds a lead to a campaign, and attaches some files to the campaign.
Is there a way I can build something on the lead that shows all of the files for campaigns that it's a campaign member of? Everything I'm trying still requires them to click into the campaign, which can be a bunch of different ones. I've made one lightning web component from trailhead, and can do some basic apex. It doesn't seem out of the box.

There's nothing out of the box, you'll have to build a screen flow or an LWC.

What you need is a ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId = the Lead.Id and ContentDocumentId is the File on the Campaign.  Then the Files related list on Lead shows all files of all campaigns Lead is part of.
